# Grant delete on newly created table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, permissions, sql-grant

A script has to be run as user A.
This script creates a table B.temptable .
Then the script has to delete from B.temptable.
This gives an error ORA-01031:Insufficient privileges.
How can I give user A permission to delete rows from this newly created table and any other tables in the schema of user B?

My preferred solution consists of a (grant?) statement that can be run by user C to make user A able to delete records from any table for user B.

Details:

User A has the create any table permission as well as the drop table permission.
The user B is a 'temp' schema that is used by other users as well to store data that is used to perform processing of other data in other schemas.
User A is granted permission on the schema by user C, who is an administrator user with permissions on all schemas.

The table is created with the following statement (columns and tablenames obfuscated):

```
create table tmp_schemaB.mytemptable as
select cola, colb, colc from
(
    select s.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cola order by colb) rn
    from schemaA.myorgtable s
)
where rn=1;
```

Then I will process the rows in the table in batches and delete them after processing.

Comment: Creating a table at run time is usually not a good idea. You are creating a table (as CTAS?) in another schema, so you have `create any table` privileges? And then you delete the data you just inserted (as part of the CTAS) but leave the empty table there, you don't drop it? This sounds like you really want to create a global temporary table, once, as B and grant privileges to A. Showing your current DDL and DMl statements might help though.

Comment: I added more details. Global temporary tables could be an option but is not usable in this case because of conventions thhat are made in our team.

Comment: It's always fun when we have to write bad code because the project standards mandate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B` owns the table, so either `B` or a user with DBA privileges has to grant permissions on it to `A`.

Perhaps `B` could own a definer-rights procedure that performed grants, and grant execute permission on that procedure to `A`.

```
create or replace procedure grant_delete
    ( p_table user_tables.table_name%type
    , p_grantee user_users.username%type )
as
begin
    -- Filtering here (e.g. temp tables only, name matches some pattern etc, else fail)
    -- Log the request

    execute immediate 'grant delete on '||p_table||' to '||p_grantee;
end grant_delete;
/

grant execute on grant_select to A;
```

Alternatively, `B` could own a procedure that dynamically deletes from a table, and grant `execute` on that to `A` similarly to the above, so that `A` could request `B` to perform the deletion.

None of this is particularly secure, but the requirement seems to demand something insecure.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it solved the problem but in an aweful complicated way. Is there no easy way to deliver this grant, when I am logged in as user C who is an admin?

Comment: Well, if `A` had `DELETE ANY TABLE` system privilege it could delete whatever it wanted in any schema, but that's a heck of a security hole.

Comment: It appears A already has DROP ANY TABLE privilege, so granting  DELETE ANY would hardly make things worse.

Comment: @APC very true. I think having multiple interacting subschemas like this is a major antipattern and security risk.

Comment: @William Robertson I think the DELETE ANY TABLE priviledge is what I want, but only for the schema B . Is there any chance this is possible?

Comment: No, it's all or nothing.(Just like `CREATE ANY TABLE` and `DROP ANY TABLE`, as @APC pointed out.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I will mark your answer as the solution, it seems more useful for the community, even though I will use the DELETE ANY TABLE grant in my case.

Answer (score 3):

As @AlexPoole says the correct solution to this problem would be to stop dropping and recreating a permanent table, and use a Global Temporary Table instead. However, it seems this is not an option *"because of conventions that are made in our team"*.

An alternative solution would be to create the non-temporary table with just the rows you actually need, by adding a WHERE clause to the CREATE TABLE B.temptable AS SELECT * FROM ... statement.

If what you want is a table with no rows use a WHERE clause which returns an empty set:

```
CREATE TABLE B.temptable AS SELECT * FROM whatever
where 1 = 2
/
```

This avoids the problem of granting DELETE on `B.temptable`. Of course it doesn't solve the problem of privileges to INSERT records or indeed querying the table.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I cannot create an empty table since what I am doing is create the table with the records in it, then process the records sequentially and delete them in batches once there are processed.

Comment: So your project must already have solved the problem of having SELECT  privileges on a table which is dropped and recreated. You should extend that approach to handle DELETE too.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
Grant delete any table to A
```

can be run as user C to give A the rights to delete from any table in any schema.
There is no grant statement that restricts the delete permission to just one user/schema.